# Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift

I am lost, is there any alternative?

```
let swiftCourse = Course(buttonImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cover_developer"), 
                  title: "Become a Developer", 
                  instructor: "Duc Tran", 
                  featureImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "developer"), 
                  introductionVideoURL: URL(String: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Inn2K-V3NFI"), 
                  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.")
```

Comment: Can you show the Course class?

Comment: Show the init of Course class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace your code and try:

```
let swiftCourse = Course(buttonImage:"cover_developer", 
                  title: "Become a Developer", 
                  instructor: "Duc Tran", 
                  featureImage: "developer", 
                  introductionVideoURL: URL(String: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Inn2K-V3NFI"), 
                  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.")
```

Comment: Thank you! I really needed another opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The way your class `Course` is set up, presumably it is expecting a String.

Change the argument in the constructor to simply `"cover_developer"`.

Comment: There is featureImage parameter also pass with value UIImage, it is possible that both of them String or either one of them

Comment: You have to pass the type you defined for `buttonImage`.

Comment: Thanks you for your help I see things differently now.